# Add target="_blank" depending a Boolean prop

Tags: vue.js, attributes, boolean

I have some component with this props.

This is basically generating a link

```
import URL from 'url';
export default {
  props: {
    url: {
      type: URL,
      required: true,
    },
    external: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
<componentName url="http://google.com" :external="true" />
```

In the component I have:

```
<template>
  <a
    :href="url"
    :target="{'_blank': external}"
  > some text </a>
</template>
```

but this prints out

```
target="[object Object]"
```

Whats the proper way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe either of these would work:

```html
<a :href="url" :target="external ? '_blank' : false">Link</a>
```

```html
<a :href="url" :target="external && '_blank'">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong type of prop `URL`, also you want to `target` become _blank or false depending on `external` boolean, so I would suggest you make a method which will return string '_blank' of boolean false. You can run my snippet bellow for example.

```js
var addTarget = Vue.extend({
 template:   `<a :href="url" :target="external ? 'blank_' : false" > som text </a>`,
  props: {
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    external: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('add-target', addTarget)

var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  component: {
   addTarget: addTarget
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <add-target url="http://google.com" :external="false"></add-target>
</div>
```

Comment: URL type can be imported. I don't think you need a method for this issue..

Comment: You are right, no need for a method, updated answer.

Comment: pretty sure that you should use `${external}` inside that string

Answer (score 1):

Using `false` as mentioned in the accepted answer wasn't working for me.
I ended up using this instead:

```
<a :href="url" :target="external ? '_blank' : '_self'">Link</a>
```

Since `_self` is the default behaviour, if it's not external, it opens as a "normal" link.

Comment: I think that with `undefined` it works

Comment: This works perfectly for me using vue3 - when using a boolean it returns the bool instead of the string.